# Create array in loop from number of arguments

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, interpolation

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=$#
until [ $COUNTER -eq 0 ]; do
args[$COUNTER]=\$$COUNTER
let COUNTER-=1
done
echo ${args[@]}
```

When i run this, I get the following results

```
user@host:~/sandbox# ./script.sh first second third
$1 $2 $3
```

and i'm expecting it to echo out what $1, $2, and $3 are not a text value of "$1"

I'm trying to write a script in bash that will create an array that is the size of the number of arguments I give it.
I'm expecting

```
user@host:~/sandbox# ./script.sh alpha bravo charlie
alpha bravo charlie
```

or

```
user@host:~/sandbox# ./script.sh 23425 jasson orange green verb noun coffee
23425 jasson orange green verb noun coffee
```

So, the goal is to make

```
args[0]=$1
args[1]=$2
args[2]=$3
args[3]=$4
```

The way that I have it, the `$1,$2,$3` aren't being interpolated but just being read as a text string.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the `+=` operator to append to an array.

```
args=()
for i in "$@"; do
    args+=("$i")
done
echo "${args[@]}"
```

This shows how appending can be done, but the easiest way to get your desired results is:

```
echo "$@"
```

or

```
args=("$@")
echo "${args[@]}"
```

If you want to keep your existing method, you need to use [indirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) with `!`:

```
args=()
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
   args[i]=${!i}
done

echo "${args[@]}"
```

From the Bash reference:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a
>   level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of
>   the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the
>   expansions of ${!prefix } and ${!name[@]} described below. The
>   exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to
>   introduce indirection.

Comment: yep, that's exactly it. thanks for the prompt reply. i'm still a bit noob with scripting.

Comment: +1 as usual. FYI, `for i` can be a significant optimization over `for i in "$@"` in most shells (hardly worth mentioning, but I think I've seen you write it like this before.)